# WPML wordpress: how to check if page doesn't exist in a language?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I wrote this function

```
function get_wpml_page($id){
    $pageID = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $id , 'page', true );
    return $pageID;
}
```

It works great, you give it an id in english, it will return the translated version of this id, my only problem is that if it doesn't find the language, it reverts back to english.

I need a function just like that one, which returns false or null if it doesn't find a translation. So that I would be able  to give it an id, translate it if a translation exist, and remove it if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is [change the last argument](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_object_id/) to `false`

```
function is_wpml_page($id){
    $pageID = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $id , 'page', false );
    return $pageID;
}
```